# How to link to another html site only when all fields are filled in contact form?

Tags: javascript

I have a contact form and want to save the contact only when all fields are filled. 
It should return to landing page also only in this case, otherwise it should stay on the site as long as all fields are not filled properly.

There is also a error message when a field is not filled. 
How is it possible to return to landing page when all fields are filled?

```
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="save" onclick="contactSave()" ></a>
```

function contactSave

```
function kontaktSpeichern() {


var kontakt = new KontakteSpeicher();
var kontakt = new Kontakt();
kontakt.name = document.querySelector("#nameID").value;
kontakt.email = document.querySelector("#emailID").value;
kontakt.plz = document.querySelector("#plzID").value;
kontakt.ort = document.querySelector("#ortID").value;
kontakt.strasse = document.querySelector("#strasseID").value;





try {
    kontakt.check();  
}
catch(err) {
    window.alert(err.message);  
}
```

function check

```
pruefe() {
    if (this.name.trim() === "") {
        throw new Error("Der Name darf nicht leer sein!");

    } else if (this.email.trim() === "") {
        throw new Error("Die E-Mail-Adresse darf nicht leer sein!");
    } else if (this.plz.trim() === "") {
        throw new Error("Die Postleitzahl darf nicht leer sein!");
    } else if (this.ort.trim() === "") {
        throw new Error("Der Ort darf nicht leer sein!");
    } else if (this.strasse.trim() === "") {
        throw new Error("Die Strasse darf nicht leer sein!");
    } else {
        if (this.plz != parseInt(this.plz) || this.plz <= 0) {
            throw new Error("Die Postleitzahl muss eine Zahl > 0 sein!");
        } else if (!this.validateEmail(this.email)) {
            throw new Error("Die E-Mail-Adresse besitzt kein gültiges Format!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't need JavaScript for this. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: As for your question "How is it possible to return to landing page when all fields are filled?"...it depends how you're implementing sending this data to the server. If it's a regular postback, then the server can issue a redirect header after it's processed the data. If you're using AJAX, then JavaScript can issue a window.location command after it receives a successful response from the server. I'm pretty sure if you search for tutorials you will find out all of this kind of thing, and the different ways you can implement it. It's a _very_ common scenario / requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use form attribute called `action=""` so it will create a GET request to the page you specified or use `.preventDefault()` method to handle the original submission and redirect to the page you need using `window.location.href` in JS.

```js
function send(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log('form submitted');
 window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223539/how-to-link-to-another-html-site-only-when-all-fields-are-filled-in-contact-form';
}
```

```html
<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223539/how-to-link-to-another-html-site-only-when-all-fields-are-filled-in-contact-form" onsubmit="send(event)">
  <input type="text" name="field1" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```